# An exercise from an "Algebra: Chapter 0" textbook: uniqueness of the decomposition of a $p$-Sylow subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

This is an exercise of "Algebra: Chapter 0" by Paolo Aluffi:

> Prove that the decomposition of a finite abelian group $G$ as a direct sum of cyclic $p$-groups is unique. (Hint: The prime factorization of $|G|$ determined the primes, so it suffices to show that if
>
> $$\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{r_1}\mathbb{Z}} \oplus ... \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{r_m}\mathbb{Z}} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{s_1}\mathbb{Z}} \oplus ... \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{s_n}\mathbb{Z}}$$
>
> with $r_1 \geq ... \geq r_m$ and $s_1 \geq ... \geq s_n$, then $m = n$ and $r_i = s_i$ for all $i$. Do this by induction, by considering the group $pG$ obtained as the image of the homomorphism $\phi: G \to G$ defined by $\phi(g) = pg$.)

Maybe, I should clarify. We know that any finite group $G, \ |G| = p^{r_1}_1...p^{r_k}_k$  decomposes as the direct sum of it's ($p_i$-)Sylow subgroups(we can donte the $p_i$-Sylow subgroup(which is unique since $G$ is abelian) by $P_i$.

And each $P_i$ decomposes as a direct sum of cyclic $p_i$-groups, namely

$P_i \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p_1^{r_1}\mathbb{Z}} \oplus ... \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p_1^{r_m}\mathbb{Z}}$

Since each $P_i$ is uniquely determined by $|G|$, all we need to prove that the decomposition of $P_i$ into cyclic $p$-groups in unique.

Any hints on how $\phi$ and $pG$ may play the role?
First Isomorphism Theorem tells us $pG \cong \frac{G}{ \{0 \} \cup \{ g \in G \ | \ |g| = p \}}$

Any help would be appreciated. Note that this isn't simple "prove uniqueness of the decomposition question", here I'm interested in getting hints on the aaproach proposed by P.Aluffi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is resolved.
First of all, a somewhat of a "lemma type".

**Lemma 1.** let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be abelian groups. $G_1 \cong G_2 \Rightarrow pG_1 \cong pG_2$

**Proof**: Let $\phi: G_1 \to G_2$ be a group isomorphism. Define $\phi_p: pG_1 \to pG_2$ by setting $\phi_p(g_1^p) = \phi(g_1)^p$. It is a restriction of a function $\phi$.

To prove it is well-defined we need to show that $\forall x \in pG_1 \ \ \phi(x) \in pG_2$

$\phi_p(pg_1) = p\phi(g_1) \in pG_2$. So it is well-defined.

It inherits the properties of being a homomorphism and injectivity from $\phi$. All that is left is to prove it is surjective.

Let $pg_2 \in pG_2$. Since $\phi$ is surjective, $g_2 = \phi(g_1)$ for some $g_1 \in G$. Then $pg_2 = p\phi(g_1) = \phi(pg_1)$.

So $\phi_p$ is an isomorphism of groups.

Now, the proof of **Lemma 1** is finished and we can move on to **Lemma 2**.

**Lemma 2**. $p(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{r_1} \mathbb{Z}} \oplus ... \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{r_m} \mathbb{Z}}) \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{r_1 - 1} \mathbb{Z}} \oplus ... \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{r_m - 1} \mathbb{Z}}$. For a proof, visit
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1921016/229776

**Now, the proof of the main statement.** We do the proof by induction. Remember that $r_1 \geq ... \geq r_m > 0$ and $s_1 \geq ... \geq s_n > 0$.
We induct on $k = r_1 + ... + r_m = s_1 + ... + s_n$.
If $k = 1$, then $m = n = 1$ and $r_1 = s_1 = 1$(and both groups are the group $\mathbb{Z}/ p \mathbb{Z}$ ).

Now we assume the inductive hypothesis and go for an arbitrary $k$.

If $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{r_1} \mathbb{Z}} \oplus ... \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{r_m} \mathbb{Z}} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{s_1} \mathbb{Z}} \oplus ... \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{s_n} \mathbb{Z}}$, then by **Lemma 1** and **Lemma 2** we have

$\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{r_1-1} \mathbb{Z}} \oplus ... \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{r_m-1} \mathbb{Z}} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{s_1 - 1} \mathbb{Z}} \oplus ... \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{s_n - 1} \mathbb{Z}}$.

We know that $r_1 + ... + r_m - m = s_1 + ... + s_n - n = 1 < k$

Now seems like a good time to use the induction hypothesis, but first, we need to consider a special case.

**If $r_1 = 1$**, then so is $r_i$ for $1 < i \geq m$. Then after multiplying both groups by $p$(see **Lemma 2**) we get(see **Lemma 1**):

$\{0\} \cong \bigoplus_{j=1}^{m} \mathbb{Z}/ p^{r_j-1} \mathbb{Z}$

So we conclude that $s_1 = 1$ also.

So we have

$\underbrace{ \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z} \oplus \ldots \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}}_{n \text{ times}} \cong  \underbrace{ \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z} \oplus \ldots \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}}_{m \text{ times}}$

From order/cardinality considerations, $p^m = p^n,$ so $m = n$.

The same arguement works for the case $s_1 = 1$.

**Now, let $s_1, r_1 > 1$.**

Let $t$ be the largest number $i$ such that $r_i > 1$ and let $f$ be the largest number such that $s_j > 1$.

Then we have(after multiplying both groups by $p$):

$\bigoplus_{i=1}^{t} \mathbb{Z}/ p^{r_i} \mathbb{Z} \cong \bigoplus_{j=1}^{f} \mathbb{Z}/ p^{s_j} \mathbb{Z}$

By inductive hypothesis we have $t = f$ and $r_i - 1 = s_i - 1 \Leftrightarrow r_i = s_i$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., f \}$.

Now, it means that

$\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{r_1} \mathbb{Z}} \oplus ... \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{r_t} \mathbb{Z}} \oplus \underbrace{ \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p \mathbb{Z}} \oplus \ldots \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p \mathbb{Z}}}_{d_1 \text{ times}} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{r_1} \mathbb{Z}} \oplus ... \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{r_t} \mathbb{Z}} \oplus \underbrace{ \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p \mathbb{Z}} \oplus \ldots \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p \mathbb{Z}}}_{d_2 \text{ times}}$

From order considerations we get $d_1 = d_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Sylow subgroups, we could use Cauchy's theorem, saying that every group of order $n$ has, for every prime divisor $p$ of $n$, an element of order $p$. Then we can use induction to show that any finite abelian group is a direct sum of cyclic subgroups of prime-power order in a unique way. A very detailed proof is given in [Sullivan's notes](http://torus.math.uiuc.edu/jms/m317/handouts/finabel.pdf) on page $2$.

Comment: I know that it's uniquely decomposes into its nontrivial Sylow subgroups, I wrote as much in my original question. The problem is with proving that each of these Sylow subgroups uniquely decomposes into cylic $p$-groups.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The best proof by induction I could find uses Cauchy's Theorem, which is a special case of Sylow I.